# Unable to read the char input in C using %c

Tags: c, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int num1;
    int num2;
    char op;

    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter an operator: ");
    scanf("%c", &op);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    switch(op){

        case'+':
            printf("%d", num1+num2);
            break;

        case'-':
            printf("%d", num1-num2);
            break;

        case'/':
            printf("%d", num1/num2);
            break;

        case'*':
            printf("%d", num1*num2);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Enter a valid Operator");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to build a basic calculator with user input. but I am getting an error in this line `scanf("%c", &op);` I searched in here(Stackoverflow) and I also found the answer that if I put a space in `scanf(" %c", &op)` then my program will work fine;
now the question I have is, Could someone explain me this in laymen's terms for a beginner? Please. Your answer will be much appreciated

Comment: Conider: `printf("Enter the expression (eg 6 * 7): "); fflush(stdout); char expression[1000]; if (fgets(expression, sizeof expression, stdin)) { /* parse expression and show result/error */ }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` manual:

> specifier c:
>
> Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the
> maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to
> char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no
> terminating null byte is added). The usual skip of leading white space
> is suppressed. To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the
> format.

ie format `scanf(" %c", &op)`.

After typing the first  number for `int num1` you type an enter `'\n'` the next scan for character captures the new line and prints it . So as per the manual, To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format:

```
printf("Enter an operator: ");
scanf(" %c", &op);
```

or use like this below:

```
printf("Enter an operator: ");
scanf("%c", &op);
scanf("%c", &op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the conversion specifier in the format string with a space like

```
scanf( " %c", &op );
       ^^^^^
```

In this case white space characters in the input stream as the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `scanf` but `stdin`. `stdin` and `stdout` refer to the same file in the memory for console application. So there is `'\n'` in the `stdin` which you have entered for first `scanf` which is taken by `scanf` and stored in `op`. Try putting `scanf("%c", &op);` above `scanf("%d", &num1);` or write `fflush(stdin)` above `scanf("%c", &op);`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I am just curious.

Comment: `fflush` is meant to be used on output streams. For reference [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: Now I understand the lack of portability of fflush(stdin) , Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how `stdout` is relevant here. Yes, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` all point to the same file descriptor by default when run from a terminal (at least on Linux, can't say for Windows), but that's irrelevant for the question. The `'\n'` is left in `stdin` since `scanf` doesn't consume nor discard the newline character originating from the user confirming the input with the enter key.

Comment: yes it is all about `stdin` . That is extra bit of information , may be helpful in future.

Answer (score -3):

Try using 'getc' and 'gets' instead.
'scanf' is considered to be unsafe altogether and it would be wise to search for safer alternatives. That way you will have greater control over user input.

Comment: `gets()` is no more a standard and it might lead to buffer overflow so you should use `fgets()` in-order to read till end of line . In order to read char by char until you encounter space you can use `getc()`.

Comment: Not sure if you are joking or not. Talking about scanf being dangerous and recommending gets instead? gets is not part of C anymore, it was removed because it was to dangerous to use.